# How to select an option from a drop-down using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to select a category from the below html.
I tried different options, and different ways showed in the blogs, but not able to select the options.
Any help will be appreciated.

One way I am using as (Not a better one)

```
private boolean select_dropdown_xpath(String value, String seleniumObjectValue) {
    try {
        boolean isListItemFound = false;
        int i = 0;

        do {
            i++;
            String category = driver.findElement(By.xpath(seleniumObjectValue+"/div["+ i +"]")).getText();
            if(category.equals(value)) {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(seleniumObjectValue+"/div["+ i +"]")).click();
                isListItemFound = true;
            }
        } while (isListItemFound == false);

        if(!(isListItemFound)) {
            return false;
        }               

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Tool: Selenium WebDriver 2.28
with Java

Thanks
Purna

HTML:

```
<div class="drop-down">
    <div class="label_field">
        <label>Category:</label>
        <fieldset>
            <div id="Ccategory" class="jSym_select_element jSym_pie jSym_noSelectText false hover" tabindex="0" textval="Default" style="width: 350px;">
                <div class="jSym_drop_arrow false"/>
                <div class="jSym_select_inner false">Default</div>
            </div>
        <div id="selectDrop" class="jSym_select_drop jSym_noSelectText " style="height: 50px; width: 350px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="jSym_select_item jSym_noSelectText" optionval="Default">Default</div>
            <div class="jSym_select_item jSym_noSelectText" optionval="Reset">Reset</div>
        </div>
            <select id="select_category" class="jSym_dropdown" name="category" style="visibility: hidden;">
                <option value="Default">Default</option>
                <option value="Reset">Reset</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try this code:**

```
Select sele = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select_category")));

//Select the dropdown by using the displayed value.
sele.selectByVisibleText(`displayed value`);

//or you can Select the dropdown by using the index value.
sele.selectByIndex(`index value`);

 //or you can Select the dropdown by using the value attribute.
sele.selectByIndex(`value in the value attribute`);
```

In your case the dropdown visibility is hidden. So, first make it as visible by using `JavaScript Executor` class. Then use the above code.

Comment: How to make the drop-down visible by using JavascriptExecutor in Selenium?