# menu click not working using selenium webdriver through java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My code is below, I am having problems with 'Production Plan', I need to be able to click the Production Plan link but it doesn't work.

```
    List<WebElement> ddOpts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]"));
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(WebElement we : ddOpts) {
    //System.out.println(we.getText());
        links.add(we.getText());
    System.out.println(links);

    if(we.getText().contains("Production Plan")) {
       we.sendKeys("Production Plan");
       we.click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your WebElements in ddOpts list aren't an anchor tags but divs. I don't know how does the page look, but it seems you might thought another xpath. Something like:

```
List<WebElement> ddOpts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div/a[4]"));
```

or

```
List<WebElement> ddOpts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/a"));
```

Or maybe if it is a select option, use a Select object

```
Select mySelect = new Select(driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]")));
mySelect.selectByVisibleText("Production Plan");
```

see answer of this question:
[How to select an option from a drop-down using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645045/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why your trying to `sendKeys()`.

But If you are trying to click on a link, following will work :

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.PartialLinkText("Production Plan"));
link.click();
```

or

You can also try with Explicit wait :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.PartialLinkText("Production Plan"))).click();
```